# Wp8 Json Deserialize Issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, json, json-deserialization

I am working on wp app. I think I have problem with json data type but I'm not sure. First I wanna share my json data example:

### Json Data

```
[{"Id":2,"PoemName":"Necip Fazıl Kısakürek","PoemImage":null,"Biography":null},{"Id":1,"PoemName":"Orhan Veli Kanık","PoemImage":"deneme","Biography":"asda"}]
```

### OnLoad Event

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://denememvc-001-site1.smarterasp.net/api/poem"));
```

### Another functions

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToList>(e.Result);
        MessageBox.Show(results.ToString());
    }

    public class Poem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PoemName { get; set; }
        public string PoemImage { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }
    }

    public class ToList
    {
        public List<Poem> poems { get; set; }
    }
```

After that it gives this error: "Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SiirYuvasi.TrialWebSide+ToList' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

As I said I think my problem with json data type but I don't know how can I change this type.

I hope I can explain. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Array` instead of `List<>`

```
public class ToList
{
    public Poem[] poems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think it's not abuot that. But I try and it gives same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public class Poem
{
//getters
//setters
}

public class ToList
{
    public Poem poem { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToList>>(e.Result);
```